# XSLT 2.0 - how to merge sibling elements

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I merge a specific element with adjacent siblings of the same type into a single element? I feel this should be simple but can't find an answer.

My code:

```
...
<nodeX>
  <a>words</a>
  <b>things</b>
  <g>hi</g>
  <g>there</g>
  <g>friend</g>
  <c>stuff</c>
  <g>yep</g>
</nodeX>
...
```

Desired output:

```
...
<nodeX>
  <a>words</a>
  <b>things</b>
  <g>hi there friend</g>
  <c>stuff</c>
  <g>yep</g>
</nodeX>
...
```

I'm working with an extremely complex and varied document with a deep hierarchy, so I can't work with many assumptions beyond the fact that these elements will show up in some context or another, and when they appear with an adjacent sibling, those siblings need to merge.  Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Using zx485's & Martin Honnen's advice, the following seems to work well to unwrap only a specific element:

```
<xsl:template match="nodeX">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name()='g'">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/@*" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So where do you look exactly to find answers on this? Shouldn't any book treating `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-adjacent` help? Even the spec has an example using `group-adjacent` in the examples list of `xsl:for-each-group` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples

Comment: If the input can have other adjacent elements then the `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` will fail to process them all as the `select="."` will select only the first item in each group, so make that `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>` if you expect e.g. `a` or `b` or `g` to also occur as adjacent siblings and want to process them all.

Comment: Great point, thanks.  Change has been added to posted code for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT-2.0 this is not difficult. It is an [XSLT-2.0 Grouping](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html) question. In this case use [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) with the attribute `group-adjacent`.

The following template matches all `nodeX` elements and copies them including their attributes. It iterates over all children and groups adjacent elements by their `name()`. Then it copies the first element of the group and adds the attributes of all elements with the same name. Now the `text()`s of all elements in this group are joined together with a separator - here it's a space.

```
<xsl:template match="nodeX">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/@*" />
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=" " />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<nodeX>
   <a>words</a>
   <b>things</b>
   <g>hi there friend</g>
   <c>stuff</c>
   <g>yep</g>
</nodeX>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the thorough explanation!  I needed this to *only* apply this to my "g" element, so I wrapped the <xsl:copy> in a <xsl:when> statement to match my specific element, and apply-templates to the elements I wanted to process in a separate manner.

Comment: Added the completed code using the method you proposed to the original post.  Not sure if it's the cleanest way to go, but it seems to work.

Comment: The answer's approach is very clean. It should suffice your needs.